# Missing values in input elements when printing in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing, quirks-mode

When showing the printing preview in IE11 with enabled compatibility view and quirks mode some input elements won't be filled although there are values set in the page.

The problem only occures when the document to be printed exceeds one page. When adjusting preview zoom to fit the content onto one page, the input fields will be filled. Furthermore, when compatibility mode is disabled the problem won't exist, too.

Has anybody got an idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We also encountered this problem in IE11 Compatibility mode. 
This is how we solve the issue:

- We find that if we set `position:absolute` with `left` or `top` in `@media print` section of CSS, this problem will occur
- The fix is to override the `window.onbeforeprint` and `window.onafterprint` in IE11
- All other elements are set to `display:none` during `window.onbeforeprint`
- The elements are set to `display:block` during `window.onafterprint`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We fixed the issue by creating a PDF export for our customer. Thus, I cannot confirm your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did absolutetly nothing for me.

I "fixed" the issue with the following snippet of javascript code.

```
window.onbeforeprint = function () {
    if (document.documentMode == '5') {
        $('input[type=text]').each(function (i, v) {
            var input = $(v);
            var replacer = $(document.createElement('div'));
            replacer.css({ border: '1px solid black', fontSize: '10px', padding: '2px 3px' });
            replacer.append(input.val() != '' ? input.val() : '&nbsp;');
            input.before(replacer);
            input.hide();
        });
    }
}
```

What this code does is "replace" every single `<input type="text" value="{value}">` in the printed window with a `<div style="font-size:10px;border:1px solid black;padding:2px 3px">{value}</div>`.

The `document.documentMode == '5'` can be omitted if you don't want to limit it to IE5 compability mode.

The input field is merely hidden, so it is still in the DOM if you need it.